# Installing Hyperledger fabric dependent binaries using Docker for Mac

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I downloaded Docker for Mac since it was a prerequisite for Hyperledger Fabric (also listed [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html/%22Prerequisites%22)).
Now, I downloaded platform specific binaries listed [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html#download-platform-specific-binaries).

The instructions said:

> If you are using Docker for Mac, you will need
>   to use a location under /Users, /Volumes, /private, or /tmp. To use a
>   different location, please consult the Docker documentation for file
>   sharing.

So,I used the following directory: **/Users/user_name/Documents/Hyperledger\ Fabric/**

I followed the same commands as listed on the site.
However, I was not able to add the line below to the ~/.bash_profile.

```
export PATH=/Users/user_name/Documents/Hyperledger\ Fabric/bin:$PATH
```

If I added the above line and ran the bash_profile, it gave an error and after that commands like ls, open were giving error not found.

> It seems that there is a problem with the file location since I
>   installed Docker for Mac instead of Docker toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your directory name contains a space. One way to avoid this problem is to specify a directory name that has no spaces. This would be the ideal approach since once you introduce a space in the PATH variable it would need to be quoted where used subsequently.

Alternately, you could set the path as:

```
export PATH="/Users/user_name/Documents/Hyperledger Fabric/bin":$PATH
```

However, as noted this has drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks for your observation. But I tried using  export PATH="/Users/user_name/Documents/Hyperledger\ Fabric/bin":$PATH.  I have also tried directory name without spaces.

Comment: check to be sure that your path does not have any spaces in it now (each attempt prepends the directory to your PATH). Do an "echo $PATH" to check. Note that escaping does not do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!. The idea worked. I tried again by removing the spaces and this time it worked!! . However, I still don't know why the escaping trick didn't work. Thanks a lot again.